# Linear Mixed Model equation (as of lme4 package)

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, singular-matrix

I am trying to derive the equations of a linear mixed model as specified in the documentation of the lme4 package:
"Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models using lme4" [jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01](http://jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01)

In the paper, the model is described by the conditional distribution of a vector-valued variable, $\mathcal{Y}$, given the vector of random effects $\mathcal{B} = \boldsymbol{b}$:

\begin{equation*}
    (\mathcal{Y} | \mathcal{B} = {\bf b}) 
    \sim    
    N({\boldsymbol \mu}_{\mathcal{Y} | \mathcal{B} = {\bf b}}, \sigma^2{\bf W}^{-1})\ , 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    {\boldsymbol \mu}_{\mathcal{Y} | \mathcal{B} = {\bf b}}
    =
    {\bf X \beta} + {\bf Z b} + {\bf o}\ ,
\end{equation*}

and, at some point, the authors say that is preferable to work with a spherical random effects variable $\mathcal{U}$, such that

\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{U} \sim N(\boldsymbol{0}, \sigma^2\boldsymbol{I}_q)\ ,
\end{equation*}

instead of dealing with the vector of random effects $\mathcal{B}$. Then the model would be described by:

\begin{equation*}
    (\mathcal{Y} | \mathcal{U} = {\bf u}) 
    \sim    
    N({\boldsymbol \mu}_{\mathcal{Y} | \mathcal{U} = {\bf u}}, \sigma^2{\bf W}^{-1})\ , 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    {\boldsymbol \mu}_{\mathcal{Y} | \mathcal{U} = {\bf u}}
    =
    {\bf X \beta} + {\bf Z}\boldsymbol{\Lambda_{\theta}u} + {\bf o}\ ,
\end{equation*}

I can understand that it's better to use something we know (a spherical variable in this case). But, in the text, it's mentioned that we should define $\mathcal{U}$ as

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{B} = \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\mathcal{U}\ ,
\end{equation}

since the above equation "allows for singular $\Lambda_{\theta}$".

My questions are the following:

- What is the meaning of "allows for singular $\Lambda_{\theta}$"?
- Why does $\Lambda_{\theta}$ needs to be singular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My questions are the following:
>
> - What is the meaning of "allows for singular $\Lambda_{\theta}$"?

This has to do with computational stability. The objective function implements a penalized least squares algorithm, which is optimized over the covariance parameters $\theta$. The reformulation improves stability, because the solution to the PLS problem is well-defined even when  $\Lambda_{\theta}$ is singular.

> - Why does $\Lambda_{\theta}$ needs to be singular?

It does not *need* to be singular. The point is that *if* it is singular, the optimization can still proceed.

Comment: +1. I would also note that one of the main (numerical) linear algebra tricks behind `lmer` was/is that use of the Cholesky decomposition (eq. 18 in the paper). They CHOLMOD that bad-boy to oblivion and though $LDL^T$ they are able to get past Positive Semi-Definite matrices fast and efficiently.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks. I think you meant *"get past NON-positive semi-definite matrices"* though ?

Comment: Won't that be indefinite then? (Playing with words here) I think they are still working with PSD matrices only. $\Lambda_\theta$ is a (relative) covariance matrix after all. The whole equation can go indefinite (it is block-symmetric in any case) but those would take some very degenerate $\theta$ that have no physical interpretation (e.g. within subject variance being greater than total sample variance and similar crazy stuff). (I had coded a primitive MVLMER years ago but my memory is not 100% on this.)